# How to order alluvials stratums in a custom way

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, ggalluvial

I made this `alluvial`:

[image]

As you can imagine, I would like the 9-16 to be between the 1-8 and the 17-24.

This is my code:

```
ggplot(data = werkuren_thuis_freq,
       aes(y = Freq, 
           axis1 = s2_werkuren_thuis_voor, 
           axis2 = s2_werkuren_thuis_eerstemaand, 
           axis3 = s2_werkuren_thuis_nu,
           axis4 = s2_werkuren_thuis_na)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = s2_werkuren_thuis_voor),
                width = 1/12) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
  geom_text(x = 0.95, stat = "stratum", 
            aes(label = s2_werkuren_thuis_voor),
            color = 'black', hjust = 1) +
  geom_text(x = 4.05, stat = "stratum", 
            aes(label = s2_werkuren_thuis_na),
            color = 'black', hjust = 0) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Before", "First month", "November 2021", "After"), expand = c(.2, .2)) +
  ggtitle("Working from home hours in four time periods") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Data is:

```
structure(list(s2_werkuren_thuis_voor = c("0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "40+", 
"40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "Weet niet", 
"Weet niet", "Weet niet", "Weet niet"), s2_werkuren_thuis_eerstemaand = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", 
"40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", 
"40+", "40+", "Weet niet", "Weet niet", "Weet niet", "Weet niet", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", 
"40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", 
"40+", "40+", "Weet niet", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "40+", 
"40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", 
"40+", "40+", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "Weet niet", "1-8", 
"9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "33-40", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", 
"40+", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "25-32", 
"25-32", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", 
"40+", "0", "17-24", "25-32", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", 
"40+", "0", "Weet niet", "Weet niet", "Weet niet"), s2_werkuren_thuis_nu = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "40+", "40+", "Weet niet", 
"0", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "0", "0", "0", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "40+", "0", "0", "0", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "40+", 
"40+", "0", "0", "0", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "0", "0", "0", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "40+", 
"40+", "40+", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "40+", "9-16", "17-24", "33-40", 
"Weet niet", "0", "0", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "0", "0", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "9-16", 
"9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "40+", "0", "0", "1-8", "1-8", 
"1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "0", "0", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", 
"9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "40+", "40+", "0", 
"1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "40+", "40+", "Weet niet", 
"0", "0", "0", "1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "40+", "40+", "0", 
"0", "1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "40+", "40+", "40+", 
"40+", "33-40", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "25-32", "40+", "0", "1-8", 
"9-16", "9-16", "25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "40+", "0", "1-8", 
"1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "40+", "0", "0", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", 
"17-24", "17-24", "40+", "40+", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", 
"17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "0", "1-8", 
"1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "25-32", 
"25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "25-32", 
"25-32", "33-40", "33-40", "40+", "40+", "0", "0", "1-8", "9-16", 
"1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", 
"33-40", "0", "0", "1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", 
"25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "0", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", 
"40+", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "40+", "40+", "17-24", 
"17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "40+", "33-40", "1-8", "17-24", 
"25-32", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "0", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", 
"17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", 
"33-40", "33-40", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "40+", "40+", "33-40", 
"1-8", "9-16", "25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "25-32", "33-40", "9-16", 
"9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", "25-32", 
"25-32", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "33-40", "40+", "40+", "40+", 
"Weet niet", "0", "33-40", "40+", "40+", "40+", "9-16", "17-24", 
"40+", "0", "0", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "40+", "0", "17-24", 
"Weet niet", "Weet niet"), s2_werkuren_thuis_na = c("0", "1-8", 
"9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "Weet niet", "0", "1-8", "9-16", 
"Weet niet", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "0", "1-8", "9-16", 
"17-24", "25-32", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", 
"Weet niet", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "17-24", "40+", 
"0", "0", "0", "1-8", "Weet niet", "1-8", "17-24", "33-40", "0", 
"9-16", "33-40", "0", "17-24", "9-16", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "0", 
"1-8", "25-32", "Weet niet", "1-8", "9-16", "0", "1-8", "9-16", 
"17-24", "25-32", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "0", "1-8", 
"9-16", "0", "1-8", "17-24", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "25-32", "Weet niet", 
"1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "17-24", 
"40+", "0", "9-16", "17-24", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "1-8", "9-16", 
"17-24", "25-32", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "Weet niet", "1-8", 
"9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "9-16", "17-24", "33-40", "0", "17-24", 
"Weet niet", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "0", "9-16", 
"17-24", "25-32", "Weet niet", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", 
"0", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "17-24", "25-32", 
"33-40", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "9-16", "17-24", 
"25-32", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "1-8", "17-24", 
"25-32", "33-40", "40+", "Weet niet", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", 
"Weet niet", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "1-8", "1-8", "1-8", "9-16", 
"17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "0", "1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "Weet niet", 
"1-8", "9-16", "Weet niet", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "9-16", 
"17-24", "Weet niet", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "40+", "0", "17-24", 
"0", "1-8", "9-16", "1-8", "9-16", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "1-8", 
"9-16", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "0", "9-16", "0", "1-8", "17-24", 
"25-32", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "1-8", 
"9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "1-8", "25-32", 
"0", "0", "1-8", "25-32", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "Weet niet", 
"1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", 
"1-8", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "Weet niet", "17-24", "25-32", 
"17-24", "0", "1-8", "33-40", "0", "1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "1-8", 
"9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "1-8", 
"9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "Weet niet", "1-8", "17-24", 
"0", "40+", "0", "1-8", "1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "1-8", 
"9-16", "25-32", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", 
"40+", "17-24", "0", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "1-8", "0", "9-16", 
"1-8", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "17-24", "17-24", "9-16", "1-8", 
"9-16", "Weet niet", "9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "17-24", 
"9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "0", "9-16", "1-8", "9-16", 
"17-24", "9-16", "17-24", "Weet niet", "25-32", "33-40", "33-40", 
"1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "Weet niet", "9-16", "17-24", "9-16", 
"17-24", "25-32", "17-24", "0", "0", "1-8", "9-16", "1-8", "9-16", 
"17-24", "33-40", "Weet niet", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", 
"1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "9-16", "25-32", "1-8", 
"9-16", "9-16", "17-24", "9-16", "25-32", "17-24", "25-32", "9-16", 
"25-32", "0", "Weet niet", "9-16", "17-24", "1-8", "33-40", "9-16", 
"17-24", "17-24", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "9-16", "0", "9-16", 
"1-8", "17-24", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "33-40", 
"17-24", "0", "1-8", "17-24", "9-16", "25-32", "33-40", "9-16", 
"0", "9-16", "17-24", "33-40", "17-24", "25-32", "Weet niet", 
"9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "17-24", "40+", "0", "17-24", 
"17-24", "25-32", "40+", "25-32", "25-32", "1-8", "25-32", "25-32", 
"17-24", "9-16", "25-32", "0", "1-8", "25-32", "17-24", "25-32", 
"9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "40+", "0", "25-32", 
"17-24", "17-24", "25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "17-24", "1-8", 
"33-40", "25-32", "33-40", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "1-8", 
"17-24", "9-16", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "Weet niet", 
"1-8", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "17-24", "33-40", "40+", "Weet niet", 
"0", "25-32", "25-32", "33-40", "40+", "17-24", "25-32", "40+", 
"0", "17-24", "1-8", "17-24", "40+", "40+", "0", "Weet niet", 
"0", "Weet niet"), Freq = c(598, 10, 5, 3, 1, 2, 11, 16, 13, 
2, 1, 1, 6, 10, 1, 1, 2, 8, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 21, 12, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 2, 
2, 5, 7, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 17, 1, 1, 6, 
4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 1, 3, 2, 
1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 6, 5, 1, 1, 12, 9, 2, 3, 1, 1, 8, 1, 2, 4, 
5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 7, 3, 2, 7, 25, 7, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 3, 1, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 3, 72, 3, 
1, 6, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 9, 1, 8, 4, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 1, 1, 5, 7, 1, 3, 4, 1, 
1, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 
11, 6, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 6, 3, 5, 4, 
5, 5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 1, 1, 17, 23, 6, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 
2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 12, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
3, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 22, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 8, 7, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 8, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 17, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 17, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 
1, 1, 1, 18)), row.names = c(NA, -482L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Says post is mostly code so I have to add more details:
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(werkuren_thuis_freq)`? So we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `reorder` the labels of your columns. You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggalluvial)

werkuren_thuis_freq$s2_werkuren_thuis_voor <- factor(werkuren_thuis_freq$s2_werkuren_thuis_voor, levels = c("0", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "40+", "Weet niet"))
werkuren_thuis_freq$s2_werkuren_thuis_eerstemaand <- factor(werkuren_thuis_freq$s2_werkuren_thuis_eerstemaand, levels = c("0", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "40+", "Weet niet"))
werkuren_thuis_freq$s2_werkuren_thuis_nu <- factor(werkuren_thuis_freq$s2_werkuren_thuis_nu, levels = c("0", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "40+", "Weet niet"))
werkuren_thuis_freq$s2_werkuren_thuis_na <- factor(werkuren_thuis_freq$s2_werkuren_thuis_na, levels = c("0", "1-8", "9-16", "17-24", "25-32", "33-40", "40+", "Weet niet"))

ggplot(data = werkuren_thuis_freq,
       aes(y = Freq, 
           axis1 = s2_werkuren_thuis_voor, 
           axis2 = s2_werkuren_thuis_eerstemaand, 
           axis3 = s2_werkuren_thuis_nu,
           axis4 = s2_werkuren_thuis_na)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = s2_werkuren_thuis_voor),
                width = 1/12) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
  geom_text(x = 0.95, stat = "stratum", 
            aes(label = s2_werkuren_thuis_voor),
            color = 'black', hjust = 1) +
  geom_text(x = 4.05, stat = "stratum", 
            aes(label = s2_werkuren_thuis_na),
            color = 'black', hjust = 0) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Before", "First month", "November 2021", "After"), expand = c(.2, .2)) +
  ggtitle("Working from home hours in four time periods") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Output:

[image]